# Translation from unique local to global unicast address

Tags: routing, ip, nat, ipv6, ipv6-transition

is there   NAT in IPv6 for private-to-public translation like in IPv4. I know that there is a protocol translation  between v4 and v6 but did not find anything about same protocol translation . 
Thank you !

Comment: _[RFC 6296, IPv6-to-IPv6 Network Prefix Translation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6296)_ is an _Experimental_ RFC, not a _Standards Track_ RFC the way NAT for IPv4 is, and is not universally supported. There is also no Private addressing for IPv6 like there is for IPv4. There _is_ ULA, but that is not really the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a multitude of IPv4-to-IPv6 transitioning mechanisms - for an overview check [WP:IPv6 transition mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism).

IPv6 is normally deployed (and should be) with local and public IP addresses simultaneously, and when done correctly there's no need for NAT.

NAT is a kludge to work around the fact that the IPv4 address space is too small and the initial allocation plan far too generous (simply, nobody could foresee the demand before the WWW). With IPv6 there should be no problem getting an address allocation that fits your needs from your ISP.

However, if required, [IPv6-to-IPv6 Network Prefix Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6-to-IPv6_Network_Prefix_Translation) can be used in a similar way to IPv4 NAT.